# std::setw() inserts a \0 at the end of my array

Tags: c++, std, setw

```
input = new char[64]();
std::cout << "wait for cin" << std::endl;
while (std::cin >> std::setw(64) >> input)
{
    std::cout << "input : " << input << std::endl;
    ...
```

Well I assure you `setw()` copies 63 characters to the `char * input` instead of 64 and I see the 64rth character displayed on the next while(cin) iteration. Can this behavior be overridden ? I want all my 64 chars and NO `nul` in my array.

Comment: @BillyONeal : I beg your pardon ? :D

Comment: That's what `std::vector` is for :) With raw pointers + new it's too easy to forget to call `delete []`. But `vector` does that for you (at the cost of a single pointer to store the size -- which you probably needed anyway. That is, `std::vector<char> input(64)` and `while (std::cin >> std::setw(64) >> input.data())` instead of the code you have up there would be better.

Comment: Ah - thank you very much :) - btw would it call delete on a keyboard interrupt (which is the way to exit this particular app) ?

Comment: Nope. (Process teardown implicitly frees resources on most operating systems, but you don't want to rely on that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator>>(istraem&, char*)` will *always* write the nul byte.

C++2003, 27.6.1.2.3/7 (emphasis added):

> Characters are extracted and stored until any of the following occurs:
>
> - n-1 characters are stored;
> - end of file occurs on the input sequence;
> - ct.is(ct.space,c) is true for the next available input character c, where ct is
>     use_facet >(in.getloc()).
>
> **`Operator>>` then stores a null byte** (charT()) in the next position, which may be the first position if no
>   characters were extracted. operator>> then calls width(0).

You can get nearly the behavior you want

- allocate a 65-byte array and call `setw(65)`, or
- call `std::cin.read(input, 64)`.

Note that the two solutions are not identical. Using `std::cin >> input` treats whitespace differently than `std::cin.read()` does.

Comment: Thanks - what is the difference in whitespace treatment ?

Comment: `operator>>` skips over initial whitespace, reads printing chars, then stops at the first whitespace. `.read()` doesn't. Try feeding `"  12  34  56"` into your `operator>>` code.

Comment: Thanks :) - the problem with read is that it waits for 64 chars - while I want to type in one char hit enter and have a branch taken (actually I wnat to just hit enter but then the while() exits lol) - while have another branch when I paste in the 64 chars. So `setw(65)` (:sigh:)